# Why prefer /Ob1 over /Ob2 in Visual C++ 9 when there're no tight limitations on executable size?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, inline, compiler-optimization

Visual C++ features [`/Ob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47238hez%28VS.71%29.aspx) compiler option that controls function inlining. With `/Ob1` only functions marked `inline`, `__inline` or defined within the class declaration are inlined, while with `/Ob2` all functions the compiler considers suitable are inlined.

I can imagine some project that has very tight limitations on the image size using `/Ob1` instead of `/Ob2`. Surprisingly we found a project that has no tight limitations on image size yet it was using `/Ob1` and we can't find any reasons why it does so.

Why would a project that has no tight limitations on executable size prefer `/Ob1` over `/Ob2`?

Comment: Sometimes, people think they are more competent than a compiler for these matters. These people should get shot. Even when you have limitations on the executable size, you use the "optimize for space" switch, which loads another set of heuristics for inlining.

Comment: It all depends on your functions. If your classes have lots of small member functions (acessors, for example) a more aggressive inlining can lead to a smaller code size. Perhaps you have just found one project where that didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Because more inlining leads to larger code, which leads to less efficient cache utilization. Since modern CPU:s do aggressive branch-prediction, jumps into/out of a function need not be very costly.

The cache is of limited size though, so by inlining code that forces the CPU to ditch other things that might have been in the cache, thus increasing the number of misses and thereby stalls the CPU has.

Comment: This is why the compiler has heuristics, not why you should turn those heuristics off.

Comment: @DeadMG: Heuristics only go so far - a compiler can't deduce the runtime behaviour of the application, it can only guess.

Answer (score 3):

The choice of `/Ob1` may not be a choice at all, but an oversight. A major cause of seeing the flag `/Ob1` nowadays is because it is CMake's default for RelWithDebInfo builds. This can cause major performance differences between RelWithDebInfo and Release builds. I think this is a trap in CMake and RelWithDebInfo should be changed to use `/Ob2` by default.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real reason, in terms of speed. Inlining has certain tradeoffs, but the compiler's heuristic is almost certainly smarter about it than a user.

Comment: It is entirely possible that, in this specific case, the heuristics were wrong. I tend to tweak the compiler flags at the end of a project, and having everything on full power isn't always optimal. In this case, a more aggressive investigation would likely have identified the guilty functions, and they could have been explicitly marked as not candidates for inlining, but if you're satisfied with the results why waste the resources?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a compiler bug with /Ob2 with 64-bit Release builds.  Using /Ob1 makes the problem disappear.  The developer of the project may have encountered the same or a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Compile times may be slightly faster in the first case.
2. The compiler may not always make the best decisions on which functions to
   inline. Inlining more to make single functions faster, may in total make the entire program run slower, due to side effects like cache spill.